# Implement search keyword box when showing the ListView data in android

Tags: java, android, listview

I have google for a while , there  is a listview searching tutorial ,

however, for my case **it is using a custom object** (serveal string, int obj) instead of one string in list view

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

So the code like this  not apply for my case:

```
/**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });
```

I wonder the setFilter() works if the provided data is something like `ArrayList<CustomObj> instead of ArrayList<String>`, so how to fix that? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own filtering by overriding the `BaseAdapter.getFilter()` method.

```
private ArrayList<CustomObj> mFilteredList, mUnfilteredList;
private Filter mFilter;

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(mFilter == null) {
        mFilter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mFilteredList = (ArrayList<CustomObj>)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<CustomObj> newList = new ArrayList<CustomObj>();              
            for (CustomObj obj : mUnfilteredList) {
                // Compare the custom object and add to list if match
                if(customCompare(obj, constraint)
                    newList.add(obj);
            }
            results.values = newList;
            results.count = newList.size();
            return results;
        }
        };
    }
    return mFilter;
}
```